# parsing FHIR bundles in Java using JSON (cont.)

Tags: java, json, hl7-fhir

This is a follow-up to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976087/parsing-fhir-bundles-in-java-using-json) question from 4 months ago.  I also need to use the FHIR *org.hl7.fhir.instance.formats.JsonParser* to parse JSON strings that have the value "Bundle" assigned to their *resourceType* fields.  Here are my 2 questions:

1. While I wait for gForce access approval, is the only file that I need to download to patch the problem **JsonParser.java**?  I'm currently using FHIR 0.81.  Can I assume that this single file patch will be compatible with the rest of version 0.81?
2. Wouldn't it be more consistent if an aggregation of Resources, such as Bundle, were also itself a Resource?  Unfortunately, assigning a non-resource value ("Bundle") to the *resourceType* field requires special handling in code that type checks different representations of resources, that persists those representations, and that transforms those representations.

Comment: For FHIR gForge read-only access, use "anonymous" with your email address as the password. And if you use gForge, make sure that you use the DSTU branch if you are using the DSTU

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely that you can change just the json parser without everything, but if it compiles, by all means

We're planning to make an aggregation of resources to be a type of resource too, but we haven't had time to get to that

Comment: Thanks, Grahame.  It looks like I should rebuild all the Java code to get a consistent version.  The version I would be building, however, would be an interim version whose stability is hard to gauge.  I'm currently using version 0.81, is the next scheduled release coming soon?

Comment: 0.0.81? Not sure why you'd need to rebuild all the code. There should be a release in the next few weeks

Comment: Yes, we're using the 0.0.81 Java version of FHIR now (fhir-0.0.81-java-0.81.zip), but eagerly await the new version.  Thanks for your help.